# Location of .bst files

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I'm using Windows, and I found my `.bst` files (such as `plain.bst`) inside the directory `MiKTeX 2.8/bibtex/bst/base`. If I want to add a new `.bst` file of my own, should I add it into this directory, or can I add it into the same directory as the `.tex` file?

Comment: it should be possible to add the file to the same directory as the .tex file.  i'd advise against putting it into the main `.../bst/base` directory; if you put it there, it will go away the next time you install a new version of tex live (or whatever distribution you're using).  but since i'm not using tex on windows, someone who is can give an answer with more authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. add it into the same directory as the `.tex` file (if you dont use `.bst` frequently)
2. [Which is the best directory to keep .sty files where MiKTeX can find them ?](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html#styfiles) and [Window walkthrough is shown in Figure 4.4](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html)

Comment: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).